# Проблема с натяжкой 3го уровня меню на MODX

Tags: modx

Помогите пожалуйста, как быть в данной ситуации, есть статичная верстка меню.

```
<ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="">Ссылка номер 1</a>
                                                <span class="mega-menu-line"></span>
                                                <div class="second-cat">
                                                    <ul class="row">
                                                        <li class="col-4">
                                                            <img src="img/benefit/2_1.png" alt="">
                                                            <a href="">Внутренняя Ссылка номер 1</a>
                                                        </li >
                                                        <li class="col-4">
                                                            <img src="img/benefit/2_1.png" alt="">
                                                            <a href="">Внутренняя Ссылка номер 2</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="col-4">
                                                            <img src="img/benefit/2_1.png" alt="">
                                                            <a href="">Внутренняя Ссылка номер 3</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="col-4">
                                                            <img src="img/benefit/2_1.png" alt="">
                                                            <a href="">Внутренняя Ссылка номер 4</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="col-4">
                                                            <img src="img/benefit/2_1.png" alt="">
                                                            <a href="">Внутренняя Ссылка номер 5</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>   
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="">Ссылка номер 2</a>
                                                <span class="mega-menu-line"></span>
                                                <div class="second-cat">
                                                    <ul class="row">
                                                        <li class="col-4">
                                                            <img src="img/benefit/2_1.png" alt="">
                                                            <a href="">Внутренняя Ссылка номер 3</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="col-4">
                                                            <img src="img/benefit/2_1.png" alt="">
                                                            <a href="">Внутренняя Ссылка номер 4</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="col-4">
                                                            <img src="img/benefit/2_1.png" alt="">
                                                            <a href="">Внутренняя Ссылка номер 5</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="col-4">
                                                            <img src="img/benefit/2_1.png" alt="">
                                                            <a href="">Внутренняя Ссылка номер 4</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="col-4">
                                                            <img src="img/benefit/2_1.png" alt="">
                                                            <a href="">Внутренняя Ссылка номер 5</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="">Ссылка номер 3</a>
                                                <span class="mega-menu-line"></span>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
```

И есть сниппет вывода его в динамике

```
[[pdoMenu?
                            &parents=`0`
                            &tplOuter=`@INLINE <ul>[[+wrapper]]</ul>`
                            &tpl=`@INLINE <li><a href="[[+link]]">[[+menutitle]]</a>[[+wrapper]]</li>`
                            &tplInner=`@INLINE <div class="mega-menu"><ul>[[+wrapper]]</ul></div>`
                            &tplInnerRow=`@INLINE <li><a href="[[+link]]">[[+menutitle]]<span class="mega-menu-line"></span>[[+wrapper]]</a>`

                        ]]
```

а теперь главный вопрос, как оформить 3й уровень меню, если доступны только шаблон главных разделов меню и дочерних. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Давайте посмотрим что получается на выходе модХ. Можете скопировать код или прислать (если можно тут) ссылку на сайт с проблемой.

Comment: aiklicense.ru - ссылка на сайт. Меню на десктопной версии

Comment: Я не успел посмотреть полностью, вероятно вы ведете эксперементы. Но, то что я увидел: кривая вёрстка, стили и вывод информации. Лучше его переделать полностью.

Comment: сделал через феном) обычным условием